# Draw Bitmap with alpha channel

Tags: c#, .net, windows, gdi+, gdi

I have a `Format32bppArgb` backbuffer, where I draw some lines:

```
var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0));
var rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    int x1 = rnd.Next(ClientRectangle.Left, ClientRectangle.Right);
    int y1 = rnd.Next(ClientRectangle.Top, ClientRectangle.Bottom);
    int x2 = rnd.Next(ClientRectangle.Left, ClientRectangle.Right);
    int y2 = rnd.Next(ClientRectangle.Top, ClientRectangle.Bottom);
    Color color = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(0, 255), rnd.Next(0, 255), rnd.Next(0, 255));

    g.DrawLine(new Pen(color), x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

Now I want to copy `bitmap` in `Paint` event. I do it like this:

```
void Form1Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmap, 0, 0);
}
```

Hovewer, the `DrawImageUnscaled` copies pixels and applies the alpha channel, thus pixels with alpha == 0 won't have any effect. But I need raw byte copy, so pixels with alpha == 0 are also copied. So the result of these operations should be that `e.Graphics` contains exact byte-copy of the `bitmap`. How to do that?

> **Summary:** When drawing a bitmap, I don't want to apply the alpha channel, I merely want to copy the pixels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set [Graphics.CompositingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.compositingmode(v=VS.90).aspx) to [CompositingMode.SourceCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.compositingmode(v=VS.90).aspx) before drawing your image.